# Spark SBT program tries to read from local file system instead of hdfs in IntelliJ Project

Tags: scala, hadoop, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I have a working install of Hadoop (hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz) and Spark (spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz). Both are configured properly to work together.

I was able to follow the scala version of [this](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html) Hands-On tutorial in-order to read files stored on `hdfs` and apply ALS algorithm to give recommendations.

**However now when I tried to do the same thing in IntelliJ IDE, I get this error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/data/movielens/medium
```

I suppose that I am missing some VM parameter or other configuration within IntelliJ but I have no clue what it is.

**Can some one explain me this behavior and how should I fix it?**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using linux-based os, you may need to give the full path to the location where you installed the data directory in your local file system. e.g.

```
val movieLensHomeDir = "file:///Users/user/training-downloads/data/movielens/medium"
sc.textFile(movieLensHomeDir, "ratings.dat")
```

Compare this to hdfs, where you were likely able to give the path in hdfs, rather than the local filesystem.

```
val movieLensHomeDir = "/data/movielens/medium"
sc.textFile(movieLensHomeDir, "ratings.dat")
```

or as [the Spark docs indicate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html):

> To access Hadoop data from Spark, just use a hdfs:// URL (typically
>   hdfs://:9000/path, but you can find the right URL on your
>   Hadoop Namenode’s web UI).

```
val movieLensHomeDir = "hdfs://<namenode>:9000/data/movielens/medium"
sc.textFile(movieLensHomeDir, "ratings.dat")
```

Comment: And sometimes you need to write the domain and port, when using HDFS

Comment: Good point @AlbertoBonsanto, I added an example with namenode and port.

Comment: Thanks @JMaurer, but this requires editing the source code, instead I want to pass the datatset file location as a command line argument, any suggestions on that? I am using Fedora.

Comment: Try passing the string values I listed in movieLensHomeDir as the argument.

Comment: Tried that , I get `Incomplete HDFS URI, no host` error

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//this is your input path
val text_file = sc.textFile("hdfs://...")
//or 
val text_file = sc.textFile("your local path") 

//mapping and reduscing 
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

//output path
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...") or
counts.saveAsTextFile("your local file system path")
```